# CSS selector not selecting h1 element

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am going to include the full code, since I am not sure where the problem is but the element I'm trying to target is the  `<h1>PC Lee</h1>`, I am trying to change the font color to white but it is not working:

```
{% extends 'core/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'core/style/index2.css' %}" />

<!--links specific to style sheet 2 -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300" rel="stylesheet">{% endblock %}

{% block body %}


    <div id="jumbotron">

        <ul>
            <li class="align_left"><a href="#">PCLee</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Repairs/Upgrades</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Networking</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Remote Backups</a></li>
            <li class="align_right"><a href="#">Data Recovery</a></li>

        </ul>

    <div id="h1_div"><h1>PC Lee</h1>
            <img id="image" src="{% static "core/images/logo.png" %}" alt="My image" height="400" width="200"/>
    </div>

    </div>
<h1>dafs</h1>

    <div id="grid">
        <div id="content">
            <h1>About Us</h1>
            <img src="{% static "core/images/first_img.jpeg" %}" alt="My image"/>
            <p>PCLee Computer has been dedicated to providing outstanding technical support to the New York Tri-State area for over 10 years. Specializing in computer sales, repair services, and networking. We have grown our business with individualized attention, honest diagnosis and fast turn-around. PCLee Computer prides itself on customer satisfaction. </p>
            <p>Our technicians can assist your home or office computer repairs, computer setup, software and operating system upgrades, internet connection problems, wireless networking, peripherals (cameras, scanners, printers, iPods,), spyware and virus removal, and all other frustrating computer problems.</p>
        </div>

        <div id="contact_form">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <form role="form" action="" method="post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <p>Full Name: <input type="text"></p>
                <p>Email:<input type="text"></p>
                Inquiry:<textarea></textarea>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>


{% endblock %}
```

and the css:

```
h1{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    color: white !important;
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

none of these css statements are effecting the `h1` element, but the css file is properly linked because all of the other css statements are working. Thanks for any help

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem given your code. Please create a [mcve] here in the question.

Comment: You say the other css statements are working, but none are shown.  Do you have other css that may also affect an h1?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
  #h1_div h1 {
    color: white;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your CSS file loaded. If it is loaded it can be overwritten by below CSS file.
Keep your custom CSS file below the CSS file you referenced.

Answer (score -1):

You may have a CSS file being loaded after your custom one, overriding the desired properties.